# Runtime error while recursively calling a function with a double pointer as its default argument in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to delete a node in a binary search tree. But before deleting the node we first have to search if the node exists and that I am checking in my search function which returns the address of the node where the match is found.

**What is the problem:**

After execution, the program throws an exception: `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` And I believe the problem is with the statement `(*parent) = root;`But I don't know why it does so. And how to fix it.

**My code:**

***Struct Defined As:***

```
struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *left, *right;
};
```

***Search function:***

```
tree * search(tree *root, int value, tree **parent = NULL){

    tree * target = NULL;
    if (!root) return root;
    if (root->data == value) return root;
    if (value < root->data){
        // This returns the matched node
        target = search(root->left, value);
        // and this stores the parent of the matched node
        if (root->left->data == value)
            (*parent) = root;
    } else {
        target = search(root->right, value);
        if (root->right->data == value)
            (*parent) = root;
    }
    return target;
}
```

***Delete function:***

```
void del(tree *root, int value){
    tree * parent = NULL;
    if (!root) return;
    tree *target = search(root, value, &parent);
    // Deletion logic goes here
}
```

Comment: in your function search when `(value < root->data)` you call search with two parameters implicitly setting `parent` to null, but this will cause an error since you assign to *parent = root i.e. you dereference `parent`(nullptr) and then assign to it

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is that `*parent=...` is an assignment. That requires that `parent` is a valid (non-null) pointer. Yet you use `nullptr` as the default value of `parent`.

You'll need to fix the design of this function. This is not the only flaw.

Comment: In what way I need to fix the design ? Can you give the suggestions ? And I don't understand you the solution quite well can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Well, if `search(root->left, value, parent)` failed to find something, should you really be updating `target` ?

Comment: Wouldn't the `if (root->left->data == value)` statement prevent `parent` to change if `search(root->left, value, parent)` Failed ?